# 2017 Individual MMATHS #12 Solution

Tags: geometry, circles

I was having trouble with the last question (in the title), so I went to the solutions PDF and found a bunch of typos. I sorta drew it out (sorry IDK how to get my drawing into here), then I got to this part:

Therefore, $\frac{YZ}{Y'Z'} = \frac{X';Y}{X'Y'}$, so if we want $Z$ to be chosen so that $YZ$ is maximal, we need to maximize $X39; Y$.

The ; then 39; really confused me, and the [solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx9KJIM_Ht8kbGxRYVVKSTJaWkU/view) doesn't even have a diagram.

It would help if one of you guys clarified and posted a solution. Thanks.

Comment: May be wrong, but it appears that 39; is ASCII for '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very nice question and solution (but with some typos unfortunately).

[image]